# how to add a custom attribute x509 certificates

Tags: security, x509certificate

is there a way we can add additional attribute x509 certificate. I am using vs.net command tools to generate the x509 certificates. once i want add a custom attribute to it. is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Found a answer here. we may have to extensions for this. Hope it may help somebody 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/73cd6a19-c949-445c-9396-4983bc8809b0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509extension%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Can you expand this answer a bit to summarize the steps involved? Just in case something happens to MSDN...

Comment: The link does not have any information on how! Hence downvoting the answer!

Comment: A quick, laymen's-terms, explanation would be nice for this thread instead of a link.